# Expression used with Rotary Encoders

Tags: mobile-robot

While I am reading and collecting information about rotary encoders , I faced some troubles about the meaning of some expressions concerned with encoder ,which make me to be confused and stray,  these expressions or words are :

-Count per revolution (rotation)

-Pulse per revolution

-Tick per revolution

-Transitions per revolutions

-Number of transitions

-Number of state changes

I thought the transition is same as state changes which means change from high to low or low to high , but what about the others what is the diffenece among them (count , tick ,pulse ,transition .... etc)? and what the relationship between transitions and pulse ? Could anyone clarify that , please

Comment: For info, broad and detailed (not pin pointing to your question) education material in http://www.ia.omron.com/support/faq/5/34.html http://www.ia.omron.com/support/guide/34/overview.html http://www.ia.omron.com/products/category/sensors/rotary-encoders/incremental/index.html

Comment: Is there a particular page or datasheet that you're looking at (if so, can you post its URL), or are these expressions from a lot of different places?

Answer (score 2):

A quadrature encoder has two output channels.

**Pulses per revolution**
Looking at *one* output channel of the encoder, the number of pulses per revolution is the number of rising edges per revolution.

**Counts per revolution**
Combining the two encoder outputs, and counting every rising and falling edge gives the number of counts per resolution.

CPR = 4 x PPR

[image: Quadrature Encoder Signal]

As for Transitions and State Changes per revolution, I would guess that these are equivalent to Counts.